# My chrome extension does't function if I have multiple windows opened but it works if one window is opened even with multiple tabs opened

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension works only if I have one window opened, it also works fine if I have multiple tabs opened in one window

but as soon as i open more windows, my chrome extension doesn't work

is it a problem of permissions?

I'm currently using only the `activeTab` premission

and `"run_at": "document_end"`

How to make my chrome extension works when the user have multiple chrome windows opened ?

so basically my extension takes a screenshot of the active tab and then the user adds a title a description send it to my app

`background.js`

```
// promisify getTabs from chrome api
function getTabs(options) {
  return new Promise((fulfill) => {
    chrome.tabs.query(options, fulfill)
  })
}

function captureCurrentTab(options) {
  return new Promise((fulfill) => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, options, (base64Data) => {
      fulfill(base64Data.split('base64,')[1])
    })
  })
}

const functions = {
  getTabs,
  captureCurrentTab,
}

async function sendToContentApp(message) {
  const tabs = await getTabs({active: true})
  if (tabs && tabs[0]) {
    return new Promise((fulfill) => {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, message, fulfill)
    })
  } else {
    return Promise.resolve(null)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'll edit my question

Comment: I guess the problem is that `{active: true}` should be `{active: true, currentWindow: true}`

Comment: Thanks I’ll test this suggestion

Comment: @wOxxOm yes it worked, adding `currentWindow: true` fixed the problem